# Fortran memory management

Tags: arrays, memory-management, fortran

I run a simulation code over a coupe days and try therefore to decrease the computational affords as much as possible. For the main simulation I have 8 arrays with 1.3E+8 entries (256x512x1024) but every couple hours I need to do intense data processing which takes another 200(!!!) of these arrays for a short time. At first I had exclusively used static arrays, which produced errors when because I exceeded my memory. That's what I don't understand, I thought if that happens the data is stored on hard drive memory (that whats my swap is for)?

Anyways, Now I use dynamic allocated arrays but I am not sure if I do it right.
I basically allocate all 200 arrays at the beginning and deallocate them at the end of my Main routine. Would there be an advantage if I just allocate the arrays when I need them and deallocate them immediately after? Is there a benefit in runtime?

A bit to the code: it is written in fortran and compiled with ifort + OpenMPI for parallelisation. I run it on gentoo.

Comment: Static arrays tend to be put onto the stack, the stack size usually is limited in its size, that's where you might see the problem with the large array from. Dynamically allocated arrays are put onto the heap, which is usually only limited by the capacity of the computer. Allocation and deallocation imply some runtime costs, but if you do not need all the arrays simultaneously, you definitely can save memory if you free the arrays after they are not needed anymore.

Comment: I would guess that the run time cost of allocating then deallocating arrays so they are only in memory when needed would be negligible compared to the total run time, but would give you much more efficient memory usage. If you are able to keep all of the required memory off the hard disk, you may see that this improves the run time because reading/writing to disk (usually) is quite slow.

Comment: If it takes that long to run you may want to store the arrays to the drive periodically, so that you can restart the processing where it stopped should it crash.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you normally need 8GByte memory, raising occasionally to 1.6Tbyte memory. That is a huge amount for a single processor run, are you sure you even have 1.6Tbyte swap on your machine. Given you are using MPI the obvious solution is to distribute the arrays. But first I would stand back and think carefully about my algorithm. Do I really need to store all of the 200 arrays during the whole data processing phase? e.g. Can Iyougenerate intermediate results from a subset or patch of the arrays and then deallocate and work on a new set?

Comment: @IanBush (256*512*1024*8)/(1024**3) = 1GB, if I am not mistaken and we are looking at double precision reals. That is 200 GB overall. Though this is still quite large and I wholeheartedly agree on the comment regarding the algorithm. If the arrays are not needed at the same time anyway, it most likely suffices to use a few temporary buffers...

Comment: @haraldkl The question says that there are 8 arrays, hence 8 gbyte